# Strange effect when resizing a window with scrollbars

Tags: c, winapi

I have a window with two scrollbars, the scrollbars are repositioned when the window is resized. Inside the `WM_PAINT` handler, I draw a filled white rectangle just before the scrollbars:

[image]

Now, what I assumed will happen when I resize the window is the following:

- First, a `WM_SIZE` message is sent. Inside its handler I reposition the
  scrollbars.
- Second, a `WM_PAINT` message is sent. Inside its handler I redraw
  the filled white rectangle.

But when I resize the window vertically, this is what happens:

[image]

And when I resize the window horizontally, this is what happens:

[image]

This is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

HWND hHorizontalScrollbar;
HWND hVerticalScrollbar;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            // Get width and height of client area for hWnd
            RECT rect;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);

            // Draw a filled white rectangle just before the scrollbars
            Rectangle(hdc, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - 17, rect.bottom - 17);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_SIZE:
        {
            // Get width and height of client area for hWnd
            RECT rect;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);

            // Change y and width of horizontal scrollbar
            MoveWindow(hHorizontalScrollbar, 0, rect.bottom - 17, rect.right - 220, 17, TRUE);

            // Change x and height of vertical scrollbar
            MoveWindow(hVerticalScrollbar, rect.right - 17, 0, 17, rect.bottom - 220, TRUE);
        }
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = "WinClass";
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "WinClass", "", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 600, 300, 400, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    // Create horizontal Scrollbar
    hHorizontalScrollbar = CreateWindowEx(0, "SCROLLBAR", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE| SBS_HORZ, 0, 333, 300, 17, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    // Create vertical Scrollbar
    hVerticalScrollbar = CreateWindowEx(0, "SCROLLBAR", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE| SBS_VERT, 333, 0, 17, 300, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add `InvalidateRect` to repaint in `WM_SIZE`:

```
case WM_SIZE:
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
    MoveWindow(hHorizontalScrollbar, 0, rect.bottom - 17, rect.right - 220, 17, TRUE);
    MoveWindow(hVerticalScrollbar, rect.right - 17, 0, 17, rect.bottom - 220, TRUE);
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, TRUE); //*** add this
```

Also, to add scroller, you may not need to create controls, you can just add `WS_VSCROLL` and `WS_HSCROLL` flag:

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "WinClass", "", WS_VSCROLL|WS_HSCROLL|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 600, 300, 400, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

Note, if there is a lot of painting done in `WM_PAINT` then consider overriding `WM_ERASEBKGND` and break so it doesn't do anything. Do all the background painting in `WM_PAINT`. You still need `InvalidateRect` in `WM_SIZE`

Edit ---------------------------------

When you resize the window, `WM_ERASEBKGND` is called to update the background. `WM_PAINT` is called next, however not all `WM_PAINT` changes are shown on the screen. Windows thinks that there is only a thin line next to the control's edge which needs updating so only that area of the screen is repainted.

As noted by @xMRI, you should set `wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW`. This would be same as calling `InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, FALSE)` in `WM_SIZE`.

Sometimes you need `InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, TRUE)` to force erasing all of the background, but the above example doesn't need full background erase. You can also try `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` flag to reduce flicker and strange repaint.

Comment: But do you know why the problem is happening, and why `InvalidateRect()` fixes it?

Comment: Those black lines are the edges of horizontal and vertical scroll. You increase the size of the client area, the old edges are still painted, new edge is painted next to previous edge. If you repaint the whole client area it fixes it.

Comment: *"the old edges are still painted, new edge is painted next to previous edge."* You are right! but why are the new edges only painted in the part next to the scrollbars, why they not painted all the way down (in the case of horizontal resize) and all the way to the right (in the case of vertical resize)?

Comment: I think a better explanation is that `WM_PAINT` is trying to paint on the edge of the control and at the same time erase background is trying to restore the background.

Comment: WM_SIZE does not need an InvvalidateRect when the window class uses CS_HREDRAW and CS_VREDRAW.

Comment: @Tony What you are seeing are the leftover pixels from the old scroll bar. You don't see them in places where the scroll bar never was.

Comment: @Raymond Chen Actually, they are the black border of the rectangle. They are only shown next to the scrollbar because when the window is resized, and the scrollbar is about to be repositioned, the old area that the scrollbar was occupying gets invalidated and so the drawing will appear there when I draw the rectangle. But the rectangle does not appear below the scrollbar because I am only resizing the window by 2 or 3 pixels but the drawing needs to be at `rect.right - 17` (where the area is not invalidated, and so the drawing will not appear). Note: I am talking about the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: @Raymond Chen Also, I have tried to draw the rectangle with a blue border, and the leftover pixels are now blue, so the leftover pixels are without a doubt belonging to the rectangle border. And anyway the background is erased before the scrollbar is drawn in its new position (so the old scrollbar is erased and can't leave any leftover pixels).

Comment: @Raymond Chen Am I right about what I said, or do you still believe that the leftover pixels are from the old scrollbar?

Comment: If you say so, then it's so. The answer is the same either way.